# Image to text using Azure OpenAI GPT4

Tags: python, openai-api, azure-openai, gpt-4

I have an Azure open AI Account and GPT4 model deployed. Can I use its API for image-to-text description? If yes, how I will give it the image? I am using this code. But it throws me an error.

```
import openai
# open ai key
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_version = "2023-03-15-preview"
openai.api_base = 'https://xxxxxx.openai.azure.com/'
openai.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

image_url="https://cdn.repliers.io/IMG-X5925532_9.jpg"

def generate_image_description(image_url):
    prompt = f"What is in this image? {image_url}"
    print(prompt)
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine="GPT4v0314",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.0,
    )
    description = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return description
```

The error is like;
APIError: Invalid response object from API: 'Unsupported data type\n' (HTTP response code was 400)

I mentioned it inside the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, Azure OpenAI GPT-4 models are not multi-modal: you cannot pass an image directly, so you can't achieve what you are looking for.

See official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/openai/faq?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#do-the-gpt-4-models-currently-support-image-input-)

[image]

Edit: announced during Microsoft Ignite on November 15th 2023

> GPT-4 Turbo with Vision (GPT-4V): When integrated with Azure AI
> Vision, GPT-4V will enhance experiences by allowing the inclusion of
> images or videos along with text for generating text output,
> benefiting from Azure AI Vision enhancement like video analysis.
> GPT-4V will be in preview by the end of 2023.

Source: https://news.microsoft.com/ignite-2023-book-of-news/